# Set of $r$-th residues.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let's define the set of $r^{th}$-residues in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ as:

$\mathbb{Z}_p^r := \{ y \in \mathbb{Z}_p* : \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}_p^* \text{ 
such that } y = x^r\mod{p} \}$.

I am reading that when $p$ is prime for which $p-1=qr$ with $q$ a prime that is not a divisor of $r$, then:

1. $\mathbb{Z}_p^r$ is an order $q$ cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$
2. For each $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p^r$ if and only if $y^q \mod{p} = 1$

Why are this both statements true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic, and so is any of its subgroups. Let $\xi$ be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Then for $\xi^i,\,\xi^j\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, $\xi^i=\left(\xi^j\right)^r$ is equivelant to
$$i\equiv jr\pmod{p-1}.$$
Let $j$ run through $\{0,\dots,q-1\}$, and we obtain $\mathbb{Z}_p^r$, which is exactly the subgroup generated by $\xi^r$. And the first statement follows.

It remains to show that if $y^q\mod p=1$, then $y\in\mathbb{Z}_p^r$. One may see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015072/each-finite-cyclic-group-of-order-n-contains-unique-subgroup-of-order-d-wher).